# Use RegEx to validate consecutive numbers ONLY for username in registration

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am trying to validate using Regex, when someone tries to register a username using consecutive numbers ONLY.

E.g.

- don't allow a username like "123"
- but allow "67539523" or "123user" or "user123".

Any ideas?

I tried this and prevents when it´s only numbers. But don´t know if there is a way to prevent consecutive numbers.

```
'rule' => '/(([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+))$/',
```